# How to run spark in google colab?

Tags: pyspark, google-colaboratory

I was trying so many different way to run spark in colab but it still not working. Every time I ran, I got a different error. Please help me fix this if you know.

**Case 1: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/spark-3.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7/./bin/spark-submit'**

```
!pip install pyspark py4j
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Basics").getOrCreate()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipx9j.png)

**Case 2: Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getPythonAuthSocketTimeout does not exist in the JVM**

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null
!wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.0.0/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
!tar xf spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop3.2"
!pip install -q findspark
!pip install pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Basics").getOrCreate()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bItrh.png)

**Case 3: ValueError: Cannot run multiple SparkContexts at once; existing SparkContext(app=pyspark-shell, master=local[*]) created by **init** at :5**

```
!pip install pyspark
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
!apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.ui.port", "4050")
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
breast_cancer = load_breast_cancer()
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(breast_cancer.data, columns=breast_cancer.feature_names)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)

def set_df_columns_nullable(spark, df, column_list, nullable=False):
    for struct_field in df.schema:
        if struct_field.name in column_list:
            struct_field.nullable = nullable
    df_mod = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
    return df_mod

df = set_df_columns_nullable(spark, df, df.columns)
df = df.withColumn('features', array(df.columns))
vectors = df.rdd.map(lambda row: Vectors.dense(row.features))

df.printSchema()
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
features = spark.createDataFrame(vectors.map(Row), ["features"])
labels = pd.Series(breast_cancer.target)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3djb.png)

**Case 4: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.csv.**

```
!pip install pyspark py4j
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Basics").getOrCreate()
spark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType,BooleanType,DateType,FloatType,StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType
DF = (spark.read.csv("s3a://raw-recipes-clean-upgrad/RAW_recipes_cleaned.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijk7P.png)

Comment: try following [this blog](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/11/a-must-read-guide-on-how-to-work-with-pyspark-on-google-colab-for-data-scientists/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you were missing 2 things - initializing findspark by calling `findspark.init()` and downloading your file from S3.
The below works for me in Colab:

```
!pip install pyspark
!pip install findspark

import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master('local[*]') \
        .appName('Basics') \
        .getOrCreate()

!wget http://raw-recipes-clean-upgrad.s3.amazonaws.com/RAW_recipes_cleaned.csv

df = spark.read.csv('RAW_recipes_cleaned.csv', inferSchema = True, header = True)
df.show()
```